# openldap 2.4 configure replication using Syncrepl

Tags: android, linux, berkeley-db, openldap

i want to replicate ldap with Syncrepl and i follow http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/replication.html. 
i get trouble when i start provider which get " line 79:  extra cruft after .
slaptest: bad configuration file"
 in log file.
Pls help to solve my problem?

Comment: Off topic, belongs on serverfault, but you're going to have to provide the configuration file around line 79, aren't you, otherwise how can anybody help?

Comment: it's my configure on provider **overlay syncprov
        syncprov-checkpoint 100 10
        syncprov-sessionlog 100**

Answer (score 0):

The syncprov options "should appear after the overlay directive". That doesn't mean on the same line:

```
overlay syncprov
syncprov-checkpoint 100 10
syncprov-sessionlog 100
```

Works for me.